# Table in Angular application wrapped in form, not taking in value of checkbox

Tags: angular

I have a table in Angular 6, it has a checkbox in there. What I want to be able to do is select the table row, i.e checkbox, then hit a select button and that gets submitted. The structure of my HTML so far is as follows, but it does not work:

When the post method goes, it does not take in the value of `id_number`

```
 <form [formGroup]="assetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover mb-10">
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Number</th>
              <th>Sev</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr *ngFor="let incident of data">
               <td>
                  <label class="form-radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="id_number" value="id_number">
                    <i class="form-icon"></i>{{incident.number}}
                  </label></td>
                <td>{{incident.sev}}</td>
                <td>{{incident.phone}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
       </table>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!Form.valid" type="submit">Select</button>
  </form>
```

**Ts.file**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.assetForm = new FormGroup({
      id_number: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

onSubmit() {
    if (this.assetForm.invalid) {
      this.assetForm.setErrors({ ...this.assetForm.errors, 'required': true });
      return;
    }
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.post(this.assetForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response

    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      this.error = true;
      this.uploading = false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please post code as an online demo where the issue can be reproduced using stackblitz or similar services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few problems here. Since you are creating a `formgroup` you also want to set the radioButton to the appropriate **[`formControlName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName)** so that the input element is bound to the form object.

Since you have defined your formGroup like below:

```
    this.assetForm = new FormGroup({
      id_number: new FormControl(''),
    });
```

you should set your radio button to the formcontrol name as well.

```
  <input type="radio" name="id_number" [value]="incident.number" formControlName="id_number" />
```

It also appears that you want to set the required validator to the form control (since you are checking for the validity) here:

`this.assetForm.setErrors({ ...this.assetForm.errors, 'required': true });`

however you are not setting any to the `formcontrol`. You can either use a `required` attribute or use the required validator on the `formControl`. i.e

```
    import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    //.....
    this.assetForm = new FormGroup({
      id_number: new FormControl('', {
        validators: Validators.required
      }),
    });
```

Another problem is that you are trying to disable the form button with incorrect formgroup, so change:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!Form.valid" type="submit">Select</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="assetForm.invalid" type="submit">Select</button>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppezf2)**